# Should I use GROUP_CONCAT?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, concatenation

I have 2 tables CP and CS structured like this.

```
CP
    id    tu    su
    1     7     1
    2     7     2
```

.---------------------------------.

```
CS
    id    st    cp
    1     8     1
    2     9     1
    3     9     2
    4     2     1
```

.--------------------------------.

I want to make a function get_cp($tu) to return the data like this.
get_cp(7) =

```
su
    '1'
        [0] = array('st'=>'8')
        [1] = array('st'=>'9')
        [2] = array('st'=>'2')
    '2'
        [0] = array('st'=>'2')
```

It seems like I could use GROUP_CONCAT to make a X deliminated string and then parse it...but I was wondering if there is a "better" way. Parsing strings seems like it is wasteful, it would be great if mySQL could just return the data like this.
Should I just use no GROUP at all, and then use php to group things together after I have a big list of duplicates?

Thanks! And please ask questions if your unsure what I'm asking.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()`. Generally speaking, I think if you can do it on the DB side, you should.

However, in this case, you are going to have to loop over the results to construct the array you described no matter what query you use.

As such, I'd do the following query and build the grouping with PHP.

```
$data = array();
$results = mysql_query('SELECT st, cp FROM CS');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
  $data[$row['cp']][] = $row['st'];
}
```

**Note:** This is not ordered for performance. If you need them in a certain order, then add an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: ok, just to confirm. there's no way to get mysql to output a fancy object like i described? and it is best for me to get a larger (since it has duplicate values) chunk of data returned by mysql and then group it with php, than to group with mysql and use php to split the strings? thanks

Comment: Not the exact data structure you described. I suppose it might be *better* to use `GROUP_CONCAT()` and then `explode()` on the PHP side. You are more familiar with your data than we are. So you need to make that decision. But either way, you will need to loop over the result and build the data structure yourself.